# Java HttpURLConnection - Connect timed out happened intermittently

Tags: java, jsp, url, httpurlconnection

I built a JSP script which is used to call different APIs end point (such as https://sample.io/api/register). This JSP script will be called/triggered every time I want to call any APIs. I tested my JSP script using POSTMAN, by calling the same JSP script (with different request body) multiple times, and I'm facing an issue where the fulfilment (Successfully called) of the request through this JSP script is not consistent, sometimes it success, sometimes it failed. When it failed, the exception:

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

has happened and logged into my server log.

I try to verify and change my code and keep testing these 2 days, but I still can't solve this. I'm not sure what I had missed out or anything out of my knowledge, please help me.

The following is the specification:

> JAVA VERSION: jdk1.8.0_361

The following is the error message:

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
> at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
> at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:81)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:476)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
> at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:162)
> at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:394)
> at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:303)
> at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
> at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:499)
> at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:594)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(HttpsClient.java:263)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:366)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:207)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1167)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1061)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:193)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1354)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1329)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:264)

The following is the sample JSP code snippet for API Https call:

```
<!%
public static class inteCall {

        inteCall(){

        }

        public String PostRequest(String requestURL, String jsonString) {
            String returnMsg = "";
            try {
                URL url = new URL(requestURL);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                Map<String, String> httpParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
                httpParams.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                httpParams.put("charset", "utf-8");
                httpParams.put("Authorization","3tC7xQw4zqYQSWXuzZPvtfpem2CDJ1hF32fxaqT7saSsT8Bbs3eSqQ5paTT2MXWxUPxW1BCXq7DVQTuAiGFPq7XT1jmBUTxEJQjJeqiBWroikooZrXRirYLo1fGfiVFqighZ5muk7FGr5JAMBkm9QF6FaiRjhgq3vANeujWWckuLpV7Y7jzwnst6bzT8YyDyZKLXkKgp7fQJsXbJKeP1Eh3CLnKDqapyTJicudpWuNEYXee5RK");
                byte[] paramBuff = jsonString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                httpParams.put("Content-Length", Integer.toString(paramBuff.length));

                List<String> requestKeys = new ArrayList<String>(httpParams.keySet());
                for(int i = 0; i < requestKeys.size(); i++){
                    connection.setRequestProperty(requestKeys.get(i), httpParams.get(requestKeys.get(i)));
                }

                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
                    writer.write(jsonString);
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();

                    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                    String contentType = connection.getContentType();

                    InputStream inputStream;
                    if (responseCode < HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
                        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                    } else {
                        inputStream = connection.getErrorStream();
                    }

                    final int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;
                    int bytesRead = -1;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

                    StringBuilder respBody = new StringBuilder();

                    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        byte[] bufferRead = Arrays.copyOf(buffer, bytesRead);
                        respBody.append(new String(bufferRead));
                    }

                    inputStream.close();

                    returnMsg = respBody.toString());
                }catch (Exception innerEx){
                    innerEx.printStackTrace();
                }finally {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return returnMsg;
        }
    }
%>
<%
    JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject();
        jsonData.put("payload", "E3i32qyjYJZqwoQ2qptIQ4Wx/t6aBIEz/StCFxsKDSBku8ZFItDC8+YrAA8tDMGrf3HT7G4lc/2AfkKhYBpqV+2nnwuw==");
        String apiEndpoint = "https://sample.io/api/register";
        inteCall inteCall = new inteCall();
        String resp = inteCall.PostRequest(apiEndpoint, jsonData.toString());
        root.put("status", "1");
        root.put("msg", resp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        root.put("status", "-1");
        root.put("msg", e.getMessage());
    }
    out.print(root);
%>
```